# Loading logic for JavaFX Task

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to put additional logic into JavaFX Task. I use this code to load Java Object from network server.

```
    ...........
    Tab tabdata = new Tab();
                            Task<VBox> task = createLoadImagesTask(data);
                            StackPane stack = createVeiledPane(task, 120, 120);
                            runTask(task);
                            tabdata.setContent(stack);
                            AgentsDataStage.addNewTab(tabdata, newValue.getValue().toString());
    ............


private static Task<VBox> createLoadImagesTask(final InternalData data)
    {
        return new Task<VBox>()
        {
            @Override
            protected VBox call() throws Exception
            {

                    TabContent contentc = new TabContent();
                    return contentc.initTestTabContentData();

            }
        };
    }

    private static void runTask(Task<? extends Node> task)
    {
        Thread taskThread = new Thread(task, "Task Runner");
        taskThread.setDaemon(true);
        taskThread.start();
    }

    private static StackPane createVeiledPane(Task<? extends Node> task, double prefWidth, double prefHeight)
    {
        Region veil = new Region();
        veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
        veil.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
        ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
        double progressSize = Math.min(prefWidth, prefHeight);
        clampSize(progress, progressSize * 0.75);
        progress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().setAll(veil, progress);

        task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t)
            {
                stack.getChildren().setAll(task.getValue());
            }
        });

        return stack;
    }

    private static void clampSize(Control control, double size)
    {
        control.setMinSize(ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE, ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        control.setPrefSize(size, size);
        control.setMaxSize(ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE, ProgressIndicator.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    }
```

I would like to add additional logic when the task took more that 10 seconds to display warning message. And also if the Task fails to display again warning message. Can you help me to improve the code?

Comment: For monitoring failure of task you can use the property `setOnFailed(EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent> value)` to show Warning Messages !

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the next question. How I can display warning message if the response time is greater than 10 seconds?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no predefined method and you will have to write your own logic for it. A very simple logic would be to trace the System time before the thread has started and then inside a loop, trace the difference between current time and start time ! Then do necessary action, depending on the difference !

Comment: Could you show me some example how this could be done?